# My site is getting hit by 3 crawlers apparently from the EU

Tags: cookies

Recently [my site](http://www.andrewwelch.info) got a spike in traffic from three crawlers:

- `eu-cookie-law-enforcement-6.xyz`
- `law-enforcement-aa.xyz`
- `law-enforcement-gg.xyz`

They link to a warning page about cookies from the EU. However, I've got the mondule for a popup on my Drupal site that handles cookie policy.

What is going on?

Comment: It's essentially spam, in the form of referral headers, so it shows up in your analytics system. If they are causing a problem due to traffic volume, feel free to block them (by whatever means you like - anything with the same name structure is junk), otherwise, they don't do anything. Don't install anything from the pages they link to though, as it can be malware, or simply open your site to other forms of attack.

Comment: @Matthew That sounds very much like the definitive answer to this question. Mind posting it as one? I would post one myself, but I cant come up with anything to write that would be any better than your comment...

Comment: [This blog](https://www.ohow.co/what-is-eu-cookie-law-enforcement-6-xyz-referral-google-analytics/) claims they're spam/scam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's essentially spam, in the form of referral headers, so it shows up in your analytics system. If they are causing a problem due to traffic volume, feel free to block them (by whatever means you like - anything with the same name structure is junk), otherwise, they don't do anything.

Don't install anything from the pages they link to though, as it can be malware, or simply open your site to other forms of attack - for example, if any of the scripts they provide had an XSS vulnerability, by running the script on your site, you open your visitors to that vulnerability too. More dangerously, if you include what appears to be benign code at the moment, it could later be changed to something more dangerous, such as a drive-by download of malware, in which case your site would be infecting users, and would suffer in terms of SEO and reputation.